# Get rid of old repos?

Tags: apt

I'm using saucy:

```
~: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

but when I do `sudo apt-get update` ubuntu still looks at the raring:

```
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
```

That's strange...

I definetely don't have in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but there's a lot of raring stuff in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. How do I remove it? (I think it longers my updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can check the PPAs you have to see if there is an updated version, some will be using saucy already, with others it can take some time.

There are a few methods to stop the offending PPAs being read during apt updates.

You could use ppa purge to remove the PPAs.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nameofppa
```

However, that will also remove packages installed with the ppa and try to move those back to standard packages where they were changed.

You can manually stop them being read during apt-get update.

To do so open the file for editing as root.

```
pkexec gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nameofppa.list
```

Put # at the start of the deb line.

Example - one of mine has the deb-src line commented out

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mugshot-dev/daily/ubuntu saucy main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mugshot-dev/daily/ubuntu saucy main
```

You could also remove the offending source file. CAREFULLY.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nameofppa.list
```

After any changes to source files make sure to update apt.

Comment: Isn't it strange that ubuntu still reads ppas meant for a previous release?

Comment: A new release doesn't know you've got unmaintained/outdated PPAs - I thought a version upgrade should disable PPAs. That said if and when I do anything like that I always in the past manually disable, remove any proprietary packages (nvidia for instance) before I upgrade to new versions.